# Assign C# MVC View variables to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am getting object not set to instance during page load inside angularJs code

View

```
@model IAAS_Application.Models.ManageModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IAAS";
    Layout = null;
}
```

My Angular Module

```
var app = angular.module('R1_myApp', []);
        app.controller('R1_myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, $compile) {

    $scope.initEditModeData=function(){
                    debugger;

                    if(1==0){
                        $scope.PP.Private =(@Model.PP==null)?false:@Model.PP.Private;
                        $scope.PP.Public = (@Model.PP==null)?false:@Model.PP.Public;
                        $scope.PP.Cust_Name= (@Model.PP==null)?"":@Model.PP.Cust_Name;
                        $scope.PP.Cust_Flag=false
                    }
                };
});
```

I am getting this error

[image]

I have put `Null` condition to make sure it doesn't enter inside. But by default while page load, control enters in and gives error.
What am I missing? can anyone help me?

Comment: did you console the `@Model.PP.Private` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried inititializing the object in c# MVC code and then send it it view. It worked. I am not getting error now.

```
obj.PP = new PP();

Return view(obj)
```